# Euclidean Space and Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two distinct points in $R^n$. Prove that there exist disjoint open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $x_1$ is in $U_1$ and $x_2$ is in $U_2$.

When I think about open sets, the first thing that always comes up is the consideration of interior points in which I should prove that there exists a small neighbourhood for both $x_1$ and $x_2$ which are contained in the set $U_1$ and $U_2$. However, the main issue I struggled with was the fact of how to construct and come up with these sets. Pretty sure that if anyone suggests the sets themselves, proving that those points lie there would be easier.

Comment: Try it for $n=1$ first.

Comment: For $n=1$, how are you going to define the interior points? Could you please elaborate on that, it seems unnatural for me to visualize the case $n=1$.

Comment: Can you think of some open sets in $\Bbb R$

Comment: Definitely, a circle without considering its boundaries is the perfect example for open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\|x_1 - x_2\| >0$ be their distance.

Consider the open neighbourhoods $U_i = \{x  \in \Bbb R^n: \|x - x_i\| < \frac{R}{2}\}$, for $i=1,2$.